# Statsmodels layer in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, linux-kernel, statistics, statsmodels, aws-lambda-layers

I am trying to add an aws layer for statsmodels for the code.

I installed statsmodels through pip, but when I compressed it has 96.0 MB with which I am not able to create Lambda Layer.

Is there a way to install a lighter version of the module?

Code which is used to create Lambda:

```
import statsmodels as sm
from statsmodels.stats.power import TTestIndPower

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    print(event)
    
    sample1_avg = event['sample1_avg']
    pop_avg = event['pop_avg']
    pop_stdev = event['pop_stdev']
    sample1_num = event['sample1_num']

    power_analysis = TTestIndPower()

    effct_size = (sample1_avg-pop_avg)/pop_stdev

    power = power_analysis.solve_power(effect_size = effct_size,
                                   nobs1=sample1_num,
                                         power=None,
                                         alpha = 0.05,
                                  alternative='larger')
    
    return { 
        'power': power    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a docker image for creating Lambda functions. In your case you need to add statsmodels to the `requirements.txt` file.

Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-image.html